# Something "is to" become something

Tags: phrase-meaning, descriptive-grammar, periphrastic-modals

"An atom 'is to' become a positive ion when it has more protons than electrons."
Is it proper for "is to" to be in that sentence? If it is, would someone please tell me what does "is to" mean in that sentence?
I wrote it, it's the answer for the question "How does an atom become a positive ion?".

Comment: It's questionable grammar.  Possibly idiomatic or no longer commonly used.  I feel it would be better written as "An atom becomes a positive..."

Comment: Yeah, your example makes little sense.

Comment: @michael_timofeev:  It's neither questionable nor idiomatic, but I love your spirit. I do kind of agree with you that the example is not happily worded. Nevertheless, there it is.

Comment: Related question, [“It is to be discussed”, what is the infinitive doing in this sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185368/it-is-to-be-discussed-what-is-the-infinitive-doing-in-this-sentence).

Comment: @michael_timofeev I think the linked question in my comment above has the answer. **Is to** is different from **become** in a sense that it could have various meanings such as "be going to", "should", "have to", etc. depending on context. I think Ricky's answer is to the point.

Comment: Could you tell us where you found this sentence?  Did you write it or find it in a textbook?  Thank you.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: It came to him in a dream.

Comment: @michael_timofeev I wrote it, it's the answer for the question "How does an atom become a positive ion?".

Comment: I apologize for my poorly worded question, I couldn't find better ways to ask.

Comment: Absolutely no need to apologize. You're doing everything right, and you're perfectly polite. I should be apologizing for maybe having a notch too much fun at your expense, but it's not really at your expense: I would like you to have fun too. The learning process must never be boring! I do sincerely hope you find my answer helpful, or useful, or both.

Comment: @RDLu  It would be better if you just used the simple present: "An atom becomes a positive ion...."

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613772/2085).

Answer (score 1):

It is an expression generally referred to as "a future obligation."

> This guide is to provide you with all the information you need about our city.
>
> You are to travel to their city tomorrow.
>
> The lazy morons on this team are to blame for the failure.

In terms of strength, it is on par with "it is certain to". Both are stronger than "it needs to," "it will have to," "it would behoove it to," "he is determined to," and so forth.

It can be very useful in questions along the lines of:

> Were you to tell me now that I'd be forced to listen to your wife's stories about her family, I'd think twice before agreeing to come along.

Happy hunting.

**Addendum:**

Your own example is poorly worded. Here's how I would put it:

> If this lousy atom **is** ever **to** become anything even remotely resembling an ion, then you brainless troglodytes had better get off your fat asses and put in an honest day's work for a change.

Comment: Are to blame is a nice example. "Is to become" seems to mean "will become" in the OP's sentence.

Comment: @Rathony: More like "It's in the works" or "It's part of the plan." A better way of using it would be "If this damn atom is ever to become anything even remotely resembling an ion, then you brainless troglodytes had better get off your penguin asses and put in an honest day's work for a change."

Comment: It is very rare that I witness you edit your post. It was real potential blessing from me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another exam I just found online, where "is to" replaces "will" though the time frame is less definite that with "will".

*An English exam is to become compulsory for taxi drivers in London.*