# What does the expression "If + subject + was/were + infinitive" mean in American English

Tags: american-english, conditionals, north-american-english, irrealis-were, periphrastic-phrases

I just want to ask you guys about the general meaning of expressions that use the following pattern in **colloquial American English**:

> If + subject + was/were + infinitive, ...

#### Examples: (Written by native American Speakers)

> 1. If I was to make a booking, which rooms are the closest to the pool?
> 2. If I was to say what I am, I'd be a Labor man.
> 3. If you were to buy the iPhone 8 plus, will you be able to get it activated through Boost?
> 4. What would happen to a cactus if it was to be planted in a rainforest?

**And here is what I think it means:** It’s a way to express a condition that didn't happen, and it could also be used to express a condition that is likely to happen in the future as in the first example.

Is that right, do Americans use the expression often?
**Please, correct me if I'm wrong.**

Comment: Are you aware of the underlying periphrastic construction that uses an inflection of the verb *be* followed by an infinitive as another way of saying *will/would/should* or *be going to*? If you are not, then we should probably explain the construction itself to you outside of its conditional use. On the other hand, if you ***do*** know that construction but just don’t know how it’s used in conditionals, you might see [this related answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/429514/2085).

Comment: Thanks  @tchrist for your corrections, but I've seen the this related answer before submitting my question . What I wanna know exactly what this pattern used to express. By the way, the pattern is a result of looking up various phrases on the web.

Comment: I mean, I didn't find it in a book or something, I made it myself.

Comment: Note that #4 is wrong, because it speaks of an effect occurring before its cause.

Comment: Thanks @BenVoigt so, should it be : 
What would happen to a cactus if it was planted in a rainforest?
Is that correct ?

Comment: @CryptoBird: That works, and here are two more variations: *What will happen to a cactus if it is planted in a rainforest?* (factual) and "What would happen to a cactus if it were planted in a rainforest?" (subjunctive counter-factural).  And these versions of the clause can be used with both: *when it is planted in a rainforest* and *after it is planted in a rainforest*

Comment: @BenVoigt: That was very helpful, thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

The subjunctive mood is used to describe a situation that is hypothetical or imaginary. The most common way to spot the subjunctive is when a sentence starts with *if*. In all your examples, you would use *were* instead of *was*.

**If I were rich, I would buy a big house.**

**If that were so, things would be very different.**

[image]

It's also used for wishes, advice, and commands:

**Wish**

I wish I were taller.

I wish he were nicer to me.

**Advice or Command**

I advise that he discuss this with his wife.

It is important that he be ready to leave in the morning.

I insisted that she go to school.

I demand that he refund my money.

Comment: Thanks @David DeMar so, "If + subject + was/were + infinitive" has no thing to do with the subjunctive mood.

Comment: But, do Americans use this pattern "If + subject + was/were + infinitive" often ?

Comment: ***I am to guess*** that it's actually the basic underlying **“*be* + infinitive“** periphrastic construction itself — irrespective of its real or unreal uses — that is unknown here.

Comment: Thanks @tchrist for your corrections, but I've seen the this related answer before submitting my question . What I wanna know exactly what this pattern used to express. By the way, the pattern is a result of looking up various phrases on the web.

Comment: @CryptoBird: The likely explanation is that your examples are written by people who don't know the subjunctive, and don't care enough about grammar to be interested in learning it

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think you're right, even thought these examples are written by native American speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **@tchrist**, I'm convinced that this is just a **“be + infinitive“** periphrastic construction.

In this case, The construction "**If + subject + was/were + infinitive**" is used to talk about **precondition**, in other words, in order for something to happen, something **must be done beforehand**.

**Resources:**

> http://dualtexts.com/english/grammar-bank/83-to-be-done
>
> ["It is to be discussed", what is the infinitive doing in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185368/it-is-to-be-discussed-what-is-the-infinitive-doing-in-this-sentence/185839#185839)
>
> http://www.grammaring.com/be-to-infinitive